# How to save JTable columns width, order and visibility

Tags: java, swing, events, jtable

I have a simple JXTable with a few columns which are resizable by the end-user. Now I need to save the size of the columns in any way (properties file, array.. anyhow).

My problem is the **columnMarginChanged** event in which I don't know how to get the column index.

What I try:

```
class ColumnUpdateListener implements TableColumnModelListener {

        public void columnMarginChanged(ChangeEvent e) 
        {
            saveWidth((DefaultTableColumnModelExt) e.getSource());
        }

        private void saveWidth(DefaultTableColumnModelExt tmCol) 
        {
            // Need the column's hash code here.
        }

        // More code comes here...
}
```

Comment: why do you want to save the state on each change? Typically, that's done when closing the application. Anyway, my incubator section has some code to store table state in the context of appframework that might give you some ideas

Comment: See also [`java.util.prefs.Preferences`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html).

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a PropertyChangeListener to the column in question?  The property you would want would be 'width'.

Comment: no: in SwingX, a TableColumnModelListenerExt is added to the model to receive property changes on behalf of the contained columns